# Include letters in citation year biblatex

Tags: citing, classics

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to cite Aristotle according to APA guidelines.
In-text citation currently looks like this: (Aristotle 2017), while it should look like this: (Aristotle ca. 335 B.C.E./2017), but biblatex won't allow me to include letters or punctuation in the year.
I've tried different packages, but frankly have no idea what I'm doing. It seems they mess with other packages that are included in the template I'm required by my institution to use.
Is there a way to just allow for letters and punctuation in the citation year or another way of going about this?
I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Please provide a MWEB (minimal working example with Bibliography) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering. I tried to use `year = {ca. 335 B.C.E./2017},` and it works as expected (there is only the warning: *WARN - legacy year field 'ca. 335 B.C.E./2017' in entry 'knuth' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly*.)

Comment: FWIW Aristotle is usually cited using [Bekker numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekker_numbering) and although APA 7th edition says that you should use *ca. 335 B.C.E.* I think it is nonsense, since you are not citing a text published in 335 BCE and reprinted in 2017 but a translation of a text from the *Corpus Aristotelicum* which was published in 5 volumes between 1831 and 1870.